# How to delete specific patterns with sed bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sed

i have a bash script that contains the following :

```
#!/bin/bash
##############################################################
# LOCAL COLORS                                               #
##############################################################
export nc="\e[0m"
export underline="\e[4m"
export bold="\e[1m"
export green="\e[1;32m"
export red="\e[1;31m"
export yellow="\e[1;33m"
export blue="\e[1;34m"
export cyan="\e[1;36m"
```

and when i open the log:

```
$ echo "${red}############${nc}" | tee log
```

the characters from the variables appears, so i've trying to delete it using sed like this:

```
sed -i 's|\e[1;31m||g' log
```

but always i have the following error :

> sed: -e expression #1, char 10: unterminated `s' command

i will appreciate your help with this
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `sed` you'll likely need to escape the `\e` and the `[`:

```
sed -i 's|\\e\[1;31m||g'
```

Otherwise they get misinterpreted and will break the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use:

```
sed -i 's|\x1b\[1;31m||g' log
```